# How to calculate the cumulative distribution function of discrete distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{3}$, for $x=-1,0,1$.

How to calculate the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$.

I know that if this is a continuous distribution then we just integrate from $-1$ to $x$. However, what to do in the case of a discrete distribution?

Comment: For discrete distributions we have the cumulative mass function, rather than the cumulative density function, and it is defined as the sum of the probability mass function of the distribution for all $x < x_0$.

Comment: If $x\lt -1$, then $F(x)=\Pr(X\le x)=0$. If $-1\le x\lt 0$, then $\Pr(X\le x)=\frac{1}{3}$. Continue.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, My teacher said that $F(x)=\frac{2+x}{3}$ without explaining, but how to calculate $F(x)$ in discrete distribution?

Comment: The expression $\frac{2+x}{3}$ is not correct. For a discrete distribution, the type of analysis in the answer by Henry is the way to do things. For any $x$ such that $\Pr(X=x)\ne 0$, the cdf $F(x)$ will have a discontinuity at $x$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas,is there a way to derive a cumulative distribution function for discrete  distribution or is that only possible in the continuous distribution case.

Comment: Yes, there is a way, breaking up into cases like in the answer by Henry.  But even in relatively simple situations like the binomial, one will not get a "closed form" formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Since $F(x) = \Pr(X \le x)$, you could try to find:

- $\Pr(X \le x)$ when $x \lt -1$
- $\Pr(X \le x)$ when $x = -1$
- $\Pr(X \le x)$ when $-1 \lt x \lt 0$
- $\Pr(X \le x)$ when $x = 0$
- $\Pr(X \le x)$ when $0 \lt x \lt 1$
- $\Pr(X \le x)$ when $x = 1$
- $\Pr(X \le x)$ when $x \gt 1$

Comment: My teacher said that $F(x)=\frac{2+x}{3}$ without explaining, but how to calculate $F(x)$ in discrete distribution?

Comment: $\frac{2+x}{3}$ gives the correct answer for $F(x)=\Pr(X \le x)$ when $x \in \{-2,-1,0,1\}$ but not for other values of $x$.  Perhaps other values of $x$ are not of interest

Comment: But is there a way to derive a cumulative distribution function for discrete  distribution or is that only possible in the continuous distribution case.

Comment: The cumulative distribution function of a discrete distribution has jumps in it.  But it is still a function, even if it may be harder to write down